# Fill nan based on two columns in another data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames like (WITH DIFFERENT COLUMN HEADERS) only highlighting it because people are marking it as duplicates

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['7/03/2022', '9/3/2022'],
                         'Client':['Client 1','Client 2'],
                         'Course 2':['Computer skill','CCC']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Session Date':['7/03/2022', '9/3/2022'],
                         'Org':['Client 1','Client 3'],
                         'Session name':[np.nan,'CCC']})
```

What I want to do is fill up the null values in Session name in df2 with the one in df1 if Client and dates are the same.

This is the code that I have

```
merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=['Date', 'Client'], right_on=['Session Date', 'Org'], how='inner')
df2['Session Name'] = merged_df.apply(lambda x: x['Course 2'] if pd.isna(x['Session Name']) else x['Session Name'], axis=1)
df2
```

But it's obviously not working,the output it prints is

```
    Session Date    Org    Session Name
0   7/03/2022      Client 1    Computer skill
1   10/3/2022      Client 3     NaN
```

Where as it should print

```
    Session Date    Org    Session Name
0   7/03/2022      Client 1    Computer skill
1   10/3/2022      Client 3     CCC
```

Comment: duplicate solution not working?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mapping dict to rename columns if your columns are aligned (by position):

```
cmap = dict(zip(df2.columns, df1.columns))
cidx = ['Date', 'Client']

out = df1.set_index(cidx).fillna(df2.rename(columns=cmap).set_index(cidx)).reset_index()
print(out)

# Output
        Date    Client        Course 2
0  7/03/2022  Client 1  Computer skill
1   9/3/2022  Client 2             CCC
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
cols = df2.columns
df2.columns = df1.columns
df2.update(df1)
df2.columns = cols
```

Output:

```
  Session Date       Org    Session name
0    7/03/2022  Client 1  Computer skill
1     9/3/2022  Client 2             CCC
```

Comment: that was my first intuition as well, but sadly I can't change the column name

Comment: Why not? You can save the `colnames` and then restore them.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid original index after merge by `reset_index` and `set_index`, so possible use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
merged_df = pd.merge(df1, 
                     df2.reset_index(), 
                     left_on=['Date', 'Client'], 
                     right_on=['Session Date', 'Org'], how='inner').set_index('index')

df2['Session name'] = df2['Session name'].fillna(merged_df['Course 2'])
print (df2)
  Session Date       Org    Session name
0    7/03/2022  Client 1  Computer skill
1     9/3/2022  Client 3             CCC
```